# Apache Configuration for outside LAN access

Tags: linux, apache

I'm new to the web-server area. I have a server running a very simple apache html file. I can access the file from other computer inside the network. But when I switch off the wifi on my phone and try to access the website using the cellular network I get 'the page isn't working: err_empty_response'.

The output for the apache error file (error_log) is

```
[Thu Oct 13 16:05:01.425974 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 25353] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Oct 13 16:05:02.479463 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27026] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu Oct 13 16:05:02.480141 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 27026] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Oct 13 16:05:02.487556 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 27026] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Oct 13 16:05:02.488172 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 27026] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Oct 13 16:05:02.490379 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27026] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 13 16:05:02.490396 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27026] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

**Edit**

I have a domain name registered and I have a nameserver the resolves the domain name correctly. Even from my phone I can do a DNS lookup for the domain name and it gives the correct ip address. So the firewall and port forwarding is at least working for the nameserver. Which would make a problem with the firewall or port forwarding for the apache server even more confusing for me since I set it up the same way

**Edit**
The nameserver is on the local server here so the firewall has to be open for outside sources to access it

**Edit**
The company I registered the domain name with points the 'outside DNS system' to my nameserver for name resolution

Comment: How do you expect your smartphone to be able to address that http server via the mobile network? For that to be possible you must have a working domain name resolution in place and a valid network routing that allows access from outside. So the firewalls have to be open for such requests or even implement a port forwarding. You will need to provide details about all that for us to be able to help with that.

Comment: I have a domain name registered and I have a nameserver the resolves the domain name correctly. Even from my phone I can do a DNS lookup for the domain name and it gives the correct ip address. So the firewall and port forwarding is at least working for the nameserver. Which would make a problem with the firewall or port forwarding for the apache server even more confusing for me since I set it up the same way

Comment: I cannot see what a domain name resolution has to do with a local firewall. You cannot somehow "yourself" resolve that name. The resolution has to be done by the normal DNS system that is outside your control.

Comment: Apart from that: please add additional information into the question itself, do _not_ post it in separate comments here. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it_.

Answer (score 0):

Silly, Silly, Silly! My ISP was blocking port 80 which is why I wasn't able to access the webserver outside of the LAN.